# How do you solve the "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I've rewritten the following function about 6 different times and am still getting a "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error. I have found several posts on the topic of promises but still cant figure it out:

1. [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)
2. [Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753743/cannot-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)
3. [Error: Setting header after it is sent - Help me understand why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466723/error-setting-header-after-it-is-sent-help-me-understand-why)

The following function is for a forum and is triggered when a comment is submitted. It check to see that the forum post exists, than if a parent comment exists (in the case it is a subcomment). I am using firestore.

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = require('express')();
const {postOneForumComment,
} = require('./handlers/forumPosts');

app.post('/forumPost/:forumPostId/:parentId/comment', FBAuth, postOneForumComment);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

forumPosts.js

```
// submit a new comment
exports.postOneForumComment = (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.body.trim() === '')
  return res.status(400).json({ comment: 'Must not be empty' });

 const newComment = {
   body: req.body.body,
   forumPostId: req.params.forumPostId,
   parentId: req.params.parentId
 };

 db.doc(`/forumPosts/${req.params.forumPostId}`)                  //check to see if the post exists
   .get()
   .then((doc) => {
     if (!doc.exists) {
       return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Post not found' });
     }
     else if (req.params.forumPostId !== req.params.parentId) {   //check to see if the comment is a subcomment
       return db.doc(`/forumComments/${req.params.parentId}`)     //check to see if the parent comment exists
         .get();
     }
     return "TopLevelComment";
   })
   .then((data) => {
     if (data === 'TopLevelComment' || data.exists) {
       return db.collection('forumComments').add(newComment);     //post the comment to the database
     }
     return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Comment not found' });
   })
   .then(() => {
     res.json(newComment);
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.log(err.message);
     res.status(500).json({ error: 'somethign went wrong' });
   });
 };
```

ERROR:

> (node:29820) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting
>    a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>    (node:29820) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with
>   a non-zero exit code.

Comment: The error is simple: You sent the response once and now you're again trying to send a response which isn't allowed in Express. Why is this happening? Once the statement `return res....` is executed (means you've sent the response) in any of `.then()` method before the last `.then()`, you'll get this error.

Comment: For example, say `if (!doc.exists)` is true and `return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Post not found' });` is executed. Now you've sent the response. But in next `.then((data)=>{...})`,this `if (data === 'TopLevelComment' || data.exists)` is probably going to be false and you'll execute `return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Comment not found' });`. So, you're trying to send response again but it's already sent and hence the error.

Comment: @AjayDabas, I don't know how I missed that! your help is greatly appreciated. If, you don'd mind me asking, is there a simple way to check if the res has been returned in the second .then()?

Comment: Well, a simple workaround for this is to create a new variable `flag` (at the place where you've defined `newComment`) and initialize it with `false`. Now, if you want to send a response and return in `.then()`, set it to `true` so that in subsequent `.then()` methods, you can compare `flag==true` to check if the response has been already sent. Of course, this is just a quick workaround to solve your issue. A much more elegant solution is to change your code and use await/async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of using promises. Either you use the `then`/`catch` callbacks or you can use `async`/`await` to allow you to write them synchronously.

then/catch method

```
// Some code before promise

somePromise.then(() => {
    // Some code after promise action is successful
}).catch(err => {
    // Some code if promise action failed
})

// Some code after promise definition you think should run after the above code
// THIS IS WHAT IS HAPPENING WITH YOUR CODE
```

async/await method

```
// Some code before promise
await somePromise;
// Some code after promise action is successful
```

The latter approach was introduces to avoid the [callback hell problem](http://callbackhell.com) and it seems that's where your error is arising from.

When using callback callbacks you must make sure that nothing is defined after the promise definition else it will run **before** the promise resolves (Which is counter-intuitive since placing code B after code B should make A run before B)

Your error is because your callbacks are probably running AFTER the response has been sent and express does not allow you to send multiple responses for a request.
You should make sure that where ever `res.send` or `res.json` is being called exist within the callback.

This [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) should help you understand promises much better...

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this here is a working solution using Promise.all to make sure all promises are fulfilled before moving on. It is not the prettiest function and I plan on going back and turning it into an async/await ordeal per @kwame and @Ajay's recommendation... but for now it works.

```
// post a comment
// TODO: turn into async await function
exports.postOneForumComment = (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.body.trim() === '') return res.status(400).json({ comment: 'Must not be empty' });

  const newComment = {
    body: req.body.body,
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    forumPostId: req.params.forumPostId,
    parentId: req.params.parentId,
    username: req.user.username,
    userImage: req.user.imageUrl,
    likeCount: 0
  };


  const parentPost =
    db.doc(`/forumPosts/${req.params.forumPostId}`).get()
       .then((doc) => {
         if (!doc.exists) {
           res.status(404).json({ error: 'Post not found' });
           return false;
         }
         return true;
       })
       .catch((err) => {res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong while checking the post' });});

  const parentComment =
    req.params.forumPostId === req.params.parentId ? true :
      db.doc(`/forumComments/${req.params.parentId}`).get()
       .then((doc) => {
         if (!doc.exists) {
           res.status(404).json({ error: 'Comment not found' });
           return false;
         }
         if (doc.forumPostId !== req.params.forumPostId) {
           res.status(404).json({ error: 'Comment is not affiliated with this post' });
           return false;
         }
         return true;
        })
        .catch((err) => {res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong while checking the comment' });});

    Promise.all([parentPost, parentComment])
    .then((values) => {
      if (values[0] && values[1]) {
        return db.collection('forumComments')
        .add(newComment)
        .then(() => {
          res.json(newComment);
        });
      }
      return console.log("there was an error");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'somethign went wrong with the submission' });
    });
 };
```